# Asymmetric serialization and deserialization using Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I am using Jackson to serialize and deserialize data for a RESTful API. I'd like to have a REST resource (`/comments`) that allows to POST comments as well as to GET a list of comments.

Here's a (simplified) example of what gets posted to `/comments`.

```
{"text":"Text","author":"Paul","email":"paul@example.org"}
```

Here's what the result of `GET /comments` should look like:

```
[{"text":"Text","author":"Paul","emailHash":"76w0kjKP9HpsdhBjx895Sg=="}]
```

Since email addresses shouldn't be visible to anyone, I decided to return only a MD5 hash of the email addresses in the response.

I have created a simple POJO class `Comment` that has fields with getters and setters for `text`, `author`, `email`, and `emailHash`.

Now, when I serialize the result, what I get is the following:

```
[{"text":"Text","author":"Paul","email":null,"emailHash":"76w0kjKP9HpsdhBjx895Sg=="}]
```

But I really don't like `email` to be returned as `null` here. It rather shouldn't be included at all.

Using the annotation `@JsonIgnore` on that field will also ignore it on deserialization. Do I have to create two classes, say `CreationComment` and `ResultComment` with a super-class `Comment` that shares common fields or is there a way that avoids creating additional classes?

Comment: Is simply ignoring nulls an option?

Comment: @chrylis You mean, like ignoring all nulls in the returned JSON? No, unfortunately not. "emailHash" can also be null and should be returned as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to create 2 classes at all. With Jackson you have full control of the behavior of a property during serialization and deserialization using annotations, with `@JsonIgnore`in the getter you prevent the property from being serialized in your Json response and using `@JsonProperty` annotation in the setter the property will be set during deserialization. The code will look like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Comment {

    private String author;

    private String email;

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Comment comment = new Comment();
        comment.setAuthor("anAuthor");
        comment.setEmail("email@example.com");

        try {
            System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(comment));

            String json = "{\"author\":\"anAuthor\",\"email\":\"another@email.com\"}";
            Comment fromJson = objectMapper.readValue(json, Comment.class);

            System.out.println("Result from Json: author= " + fromJson.getAuthor() + ", email= " + fromJson.getEmail());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The output after running the `main()` method to test the solution:

`{"author":"anAuthor"}`

`Result from Json: author= anAuthor, email= another@email.com`

Hope it helps,

Jose Luis

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I was looking for! I didn't know `@JsonProperty` is sort of "overriding" `@JsonIgnore`.

Answer (score 3):

You can put `@JsonIgnore` on `getEmail` to prevent it from being serialized to JSON and use `@JsonCreator` to indicate to Jackson a constructor to use for deserialization. The constructor would then only accept an `email` property and would hash and assign to your `emailHash` field.

You can put a `@JsonInclude` annotation on your `Comment` class to prevent serialization of `null` fields too.

Your class would probably end up looking something like this:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Comment {
    private final String email;
    private final String emailHash;

    @JsonCreator
    public Comment(@JsonProperty("email") String email) {
        this.email = email;
        this.emailHash = MD5.hash(email);
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getEmailHash() {
        return emailHash;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer. This solution works, but I prefer @jbarrueta's answer, since it doesn't need an additional constructor.