# Deserializing a list results in duplicates

Tags: jackson, deserialization

I have a simple pojo where i have one list of strings and default get/set, i have another get so that in json i get 2 different fields
my pojo and test code snippet are below

```
  public static class TestClass{
    public ArrayList<String> names = null;

    public ArrayList<String> getNames() {
        if(null == names) names = new ArrayList<>();
        return names;
    }

    public void setNames(ArrayList<String> names) {
        this.names = names;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getNames_r() {
        return getNames();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestClass [names=" + names + "]";
    }

}

@Test
public void testDeSerializationSimple() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
    String justSchool = "{\"names\":[\"second\",\"one\",\"two\",\"three\"],\"names_r\":[\"second\",\"one\",\"two\",\"three\"]}";

    ObjectMapper myDefaultMapper= new ObjectMapper();
    myDefaultMapper.setDateFormat(CoreUtils.COMMON_SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT)
    .setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
    .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    TestClass testReadDummy = myDefaultMapper.readValue(justSchool, TestClass.class);
    System.out.println(" mapper test read = "+testReadDummy);
    //assertEquals(testRead.getListString().size(),4);
    System.out.println("list = "+testReadDummy);
    assertEquals(testReadDummy.names.size(), 4);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

configuring the mapper to not use getters as setters using
MAPPER.configure(MapperFeature.USE_GETTERS_AS_SETTERS, false);

solved this

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `@JsonIgnore` annotation in the duplicate of your list so it doesn't get serialized, it would look something like:

```
@JsonIgnore    
public ArrayList<String> getNames_r() {
    return getNames();
}
```

That should get rid of your duplicate field in you serialized JSON.

Hope it helps,

Jose Luis

Comment: i want to field to be serialized, but while de-serializing i dont want to to read it.

Comment: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/95 this is similar, but since i am on older version, i was trying to find out any way to get the expected output

Comment: What version are you in? I know since version  Jackson 1.9 you can control serialization and deserialization of properties with `@JsonIgnore`  and `@JsonProperty` annotations as I already in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134298/asymmetric-serialization-and-deserialization-using-jackson/30147413#30147413. Hope it helps!

Comment: the problem is that i want it while serialization and while de-serialization, it calls the getter and add the to the list. since i dont have setter, if add a setter then my problem is solved, but wanted to know if i can solve it without adding the setter